# Looking for Peirush HaGra on Sefer Yehoshua online

Tags: sources-mekorot, internet, joshua--book-of, vilna-gaon

Does anyone know if there is an online version of the Peirush HaGra on Sefer Yehoshua online?

I can't seem to find it on [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/) or [Hebrewbooks.org](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You may check Aderes Elyahu on Neviim ([at this link](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/14221)) containing his commentary to Yehoshua.